# How to do an if statement inside a loop?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm having trouble with the if statement inside a loop. Every time I try and run it, it gives me an error of:

> next without for

```
Sub CheckDates4()

    Dim count As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    count = 0
    i = 2
    j = 24

    For i = 2 To 318
        For j = 46 To 1 Step (-2)
            If Sheet1.Cells(i, j) >= Sheet2.Cells(1, 1) And Sheet1.Cells(i, j - 1) = "Reçu" Then
                count = count + 1
            Next i
        Next j

    End If

    Sheet2.Cells(1, 7) = count

End Sub
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: It would be more efficient to put Sheet2.Cells(1, 1)  into a variable so as to avoid repeatedly going back to same cell to retrieve its value.

Comment: You have messed up the ending block statements. For example if [] represents FOR-NEXT and {} represents IF-ENDIF, your code is like [ [ { ] ] } which is wrong. Ideally, in the representational format, it should be [ [ { } ] ].

Hope it was easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Your `END IF` was in the wrong place and you've swapped your `NEXTs` as well:

```
For i = 2 To 318
    For j = 46 To 1 Step (-2)
        If Sheet1.Cells(i, j) >= Sheet2.Cells(1, 1) And Sheet1.Cells(i, j - 1) = "Reçu" Then
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You should first close the `If` condition with `End If`. Then, close the inner `For` loop with `Next j`. Finally, close the outer `For` loop with `Next i`. So, your code should look like this:

```
Sub CheckDates4()
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    count = 0
    i = 2
    j = 24

    For i = 2 To 318
        For j = 46 To 1 Step (-2)
            If Sheet1.Cells(i, j) >= Sheet2.Cells(1, 1) And Sheet1.Cells(i, j - 1) = "Reçu" Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    Sheet2.Cells(1, 7) = count
End Sub
```